# Why Android SDK version 2.1 contains alphabets in its version code

Tags: android

I found Android has SDK version 1.5, 1.6, 2.2, 3.1.. all these versions are combination of . and numeric digits. But when i found SDK version `2.1-update1` in this case the version code is contains alphabets also (update1). Why is it like that?

Comment: This question should be tagged as "Community wiki" as it is going to be a long discussion.

Comment: How to tag it as community wiki? please inform me

Comment: ["alphabets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet) is not the word you're searching for. You probably meant ["letters"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_(alphabet)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the version information available from Build.VERSION, from most interesting to least:

VERSION.SDK_INT is the "SDK version" or "API version".  This is the number that accurately represents the APIs available on the platform you are running on; it is the number for example that you see in the documentation for filtering our newer APIs.  The possible values are described at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html and it is a monotonically increasing number so if you want to know whether some APIs introduced at API level N are available, you can do this with "if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= N)".

VERSION.SDK is the original representation of the SDK version, but as a string which is not nearly as convenient for applications to use so deprecated.  If you really need to run on older versions of the platform prior to SDK_INT, then you can get the same number with "Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK)"; you can see that these are the same thing by seeing how they are initialized in the source code https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Build.java

VERSION.RELEASE is the string that is shown to the user to tell them the platform version.  This is not intended to be parsed by applications.  This is where you will find things like "3.1" or "2.1-update1".  Again, this is for display to the user; you should not be trying to interpret it in your code.  It tells the user the actual core version of the platform their device is running.

VERSION.INCREMENTAL is an arbitrary string tagging the actual software build of the device.  The format of this string varies between manufacturers.  It is also for display to the user, though less meaningful for them -- it is only useful if they want to know if their software is a particular build number they are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

are you sing Build.VERSION.SDK this is a String refered to as the platform version, and is not the numeric identifier for the android version (which is usually called the API Level). The difference being 1.5=3, 1.6=4,..., 3.1=12

Build.VERSION.SDK_INT was added in android 1.6(4) and is the way to get the numeric identifier for a version. So if you want to know about versions before 1.5 you cant use it. You can call it via reflection or use the minSdkVersion tag (see below) to ensure it isn't use on earlier devices.

the API level is what you use in the uses-sdk tag e.g. for android 1.6 this limits visibility of you app to 1.6 and higher

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Comment: If you want to run on older versions than 1.6, just do Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK).